# ODS import into MySQL : offset data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ods

I ran into a problem importing ODS files into a MySQL Database.

Every row and column is creating fine, and the data inside is correct for the most part. But for some reason, I have a few rows who have the correct data, but not in the correct column.

I have a `establishmentType` column (values are one of 5 : traditionnal, fastfood, takeaway, pub or nightclub), an `clientEmail` columun (which contains, of course, an e-mail adress) and an `attestationNumber` column (which contains round numbers starting from 1).

The `establishmentType` on some rows import in either the `clientEmail` or `attestationNumber` column, so I end with traditionnal in the email or attestation number. Each time I import, it happens at the same place each time, for the same clients.

I have no special characters on any content or column name. I can't find any pattern that might point me to the problem.

Is this a known bug? Did I missed something?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out exporting my ods file as a csv file works and doesn't mess up my data.
Not really solved but that's a workaround I guess, MySQL or PHPMyAdmin probably don't go along well with ods files.

Will mark this as solved when I can.

Comment: If you can post a small example file to the phpMyAdmin issue tracker, the developers can take a look. It's tough to troubleshoot these kinds of issues without a reproducible test case.